# Beautifulsoup - pesquisa de href por texto

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Boa tarde a todos, estou com um problema que ainda não consegui resolver nem encontrei nenhum relacionado.

Se eu tiver:

```
codigo_pagina = '''<li><span><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingA.aspx">
                Something1</a></span></span></li>
            <li><span><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingB.aspx">Something2</a></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">**Something3**</a></span><span><span style="font-family: Courier New">
                (<a href="page1/anotherthing.aspx">anothertext</a>)</li>

soup = BeautifulSoup(codigo_pagina, "lxml")

path = soup.findAll('a', href=True, text="Something3")
print(path)
```

eu recebo:

`>>> [<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">Something3</a>]`

que é o que quero.

Mas se Something3 passar para nova linha (como se eu desse um "enter" o href já não é encontrado e não recebo nada:

```
codigo_pagina = '''<li><span><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingA.aspx">
                Something1</a></span></span></li>
            <li><span><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingB.aspx">Something2</a></span></li>
            <li><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">
**Something3**</a></span><span><span style="font-family: Courier New">
                (<a href="page1/anotherthing.aspx">anothertext</a>)</li>
```

Assim já não recebo nada...

`>>>`

Comment: Experimentei eliminar as new lines (\n) com  ``` soup.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ''),  para então fazer o findAll, mas dá-me o erro  ``` TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable ```  porque a variável soup não é uma string. Podia fazer na variável  path mas já não vale de nada porque ela não "vê" que o texto do href que quero está na linha seguinte.

Answer (score 0):

Por algum motivo, a estrutura do HTML no PyCharm precisa seguir alguns critérios mesmo.

Testei seu código aqui e consegui fazê-lo funcionar adicionando um \ a cada linha pulada no HTML. Esse backslash diz ao PyCharm que a instrução não acabou e que está continuada na próxima linha.

Segue código completo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

codigo_pagina = '''
<li><span><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingA.aspx">\
Something1</a></span></span></li>\
\
<li><span><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingB.aspx">Something2</a></span></span></li>\
\
<li><span style="font-family: Courier New"><a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">\
\
Something3</a></li></span><span><span style="font-family: Courier New">\

(<a href="page1/anotherthing.aspx">anothertext</a>)</span></span></li>
'''



soup = BeautifulSoup(codigo_pagina, 'lxml')
path = soup.findAll('a', href=True, text="Something3")
print(path)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas como faz se o código html estiver numa página da internet e esta página tiver sido feita dessa forma (com o texto do href na linha seguinte)?

Comment: Funciona sem problemas! Eu subi uma página de teste e o código conseguiu retornar o valor correto em ambos os html. O problema, nesse caso, é a estrutura do PyCharm mesmo!

Comment: Eu não posso alterar o código da variável "codigo_pagina" e acrescentar as "\" porque o código faz parte de uma página programada por outra pessoa que a fez dessa maneira com esse erro de colocar o texto do href na linha seguinte. Por isso tenho de tentar arranjar uma solução que funcione sem mexer no "codigo_pagina".

Comment: Mas não é mais fácil extrair, então, da própria webpage? Ou não tem jeito? Se não tiver, tenta uma outra IDE que é possível que funcione sem as barras.